# iOS Siri Kit - Show user's data

Tags: ios, ios10, sirikit

I have an app which has some data stored by itself. Now, I need to display it using Siri. For example, my username in that app is "Steward", then the Siri should return "Your username in the app_name is Steward" for the question "What is my username of app_name".I tried using intent extension or Siri. But they have some constraints like "Message", "Work out", "Ride" etc., But what I need is a white plain window like the intentUI which displays some app information. Please help me with this problem. Is there any siri APIs available for iOS 10 like such? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use "What is my username of app_name" to call siri on your problem.
Now what we can do, just use the function which is supported in sirikit, like:
"Use app_name to call someone"
"Send message to someone on app_name"
"Start my workout on app_name"

SiriKit support is divided into domains, each of which defines one or more tasks that can be performed. In order to support SiriKit, apps must support one of the following domains:

VoIP calling
Messaging
Payments
Photo
Workouts
Ride booking
CarPlay (automotive vendors only)
Restaurant reservations (requires additional support from Apple)

More info, you can refer to this link:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/